# Copy multiple rows from one table to another table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1

```
Item  ----  Qauntity  ---- Code
123 1 ---    10       ---  123
123 2 ---    20       ---  123
123 3 ---    30       ---  123
653 3 ---    60       ---  345
653 2 ---    30       ---  345
653 4 ---    20       ---  345
967 3 ---    10       ---  967
967 2 ---    20       ---  967
967 1 ---    30       ---  967
```

Table 2:

```
Code --   Qauntity
123  --     40
345  --     30
444  --     10
234  --     20
653  --     60
```

I need to get sum(Quantity) with group by code from table 1 and update in table 2 if Code exists else insert a new row. Remaining rows leave as it is in Table 2. How can I write a oracle plsql query for the following scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm) you can do that

```
merge into table2 t2 using (select code, quantity from table1) t1 on (t2.code = t1.code)
when not matched then insert (code,quantity) values (t1.code,t1.qty)
when matched then update set quantity = quantity+t1.quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` to "upsert" a row (update or insert.)  The merge source can be a subquery where you can `group by Code` and calculate the sum of Quantity:

```
merge   into Table2 t2 
using   (
        select  Code
        ,       sum(Quantity) as SumQuantity
        from    Table1
        group by
                Code
        ) t1
on      (t1.Code = t2.Code)
when    not matched then 
        insert  (Code, Quantity) 
        values  (t1.Code, t1.SumQuantity)
when    matched then 
        update  set Quantity = t1.SumQuantity;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/537cc/1/0)